# jQuery - scroll to element into another element

Tags: jquery, scroll

I try to create a jQuery script which will be able to scroll div to specified ID element (this div is into another, main div). I have a problem with that because everything what I do, makes the script is scroll to bottom of div, and I don't know where is a problem.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <style>
     .chat {
         height: 100px;
          overflow-y: scroll;
     }
  </style>
  <div id="main_cointainer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.
    <br><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.
    <br><br>
    <div class="chat">
      <p id="msg_70_3">
        something msg 0<br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_71_3">
        something msg 1<br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_72_3">
        something msg 2<br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_73_3">
       <span style="color: red;">something msg 3 - HERE STOP SCROLL</span><br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_74_3">
        something msg 4<br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_75_3">
        something msg 5<br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_76_3">
        something msg 6<br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_77_3">
        something msg 7<br><br>
      </p>
       <p id="msg_78_3">
        something msg 8<br><br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my jQuery script:

```
$('#main_cointainer .chat').delay(1000).animate({
    scrollTop: $('#msg_73_3').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7uxg7ga/

as you can see, the scroll is going to bottom of .chat div and I don't know why... I set the ID of p element: msg_73_3 so it could stop on this element but it not.

Here is also another file, which presents well result: https://jsfiddle.net/kefnvqh1/

I do it because i set:

```
    scrollTop: 180
```

but this script should auto calculate this height.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the element try using the "body" instead.

```
$('html, body').delay(1000).animate({
    scrollTop: $('#msg_73_3').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

Please check at: https://jsfiddle.net/x7uxg7ga/1/

Comment: I don't want to scroll main div (and all my web site) but one div, which is inside another div (and also inside body tag), so your answer doesn't help me.